# How to check if two dates falls between two columns of dataframe representing start date and end date

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe

I am trying to check if my start date and end date falls between the given StartDate and EndDate in my dataframe

DataFrame looks like

```
TermYear Term   StartDate      EndDate
 2017     1     2017-01-10    2017-03-31
 2017     2     2017-04-10    2017-06-30
 2017     3     2017-07-24    2017-09-18
 2017     4     2017-09-30    2017-12-04
```

I am trying to fetch the term and TermYear when my given date i.e.

```
Start Date: '2017-01-24'
End Date: '2017-09-29'
```

Lies between start and end date of dataframe it should fetch multiple rows any ideas?
I have tried

```
lowerDate = np.datetime64('2017-07-24')
upperDate = np.datetime64('2017-07-26')
termDates = termDates[(termDates.StartDate >= lowerDate) &
                      (termDates.EndDate <= upperDate) ][['Term', 'TermYear']]
```

But it returns me empty dataframe

Expected output:

```
Term    TermYear
 2017     1     
 2017     2     
 2017     3
```

[image: What i tried and its output]

Comment: have edited the question please check

Comment: Solution added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
In [1820]: df[(df.StartDate <= StartDate) & (df.EndDate >= EndDate)]
Out[1820]:
   TermYear  Term   StartDate     EndDate
2      2017     3  2017-07-24  2017-09-18
```

For specific columns

```
In [1826]: df.loc[(df.StartDate<=StartDate) & (df.EndDate>=EndDate), ['Term', 'TermYear']]
Out[1826]:
   Term  TermYear
2     3      2017
```

Where,

```
In [1821]: df
Out[1821]:
   TermYear  Term   StartDate     EndDate
0      2017     1  2017-01-10  2017-03-31
1      2017     2  2017-04-10  2017-06-30
2      2017     3  2017-07-24  2017-09-18
3      2017     4  2017-09-30  2017-12-04

In [1822]: StartDate
Out[1822]: '2017-07-24'

In [1823]: EndDate
Out[1823]: '2017-08-29'

In [1835]: df.dtypes
Out[1835]:
TermYear              int64
Term                  int64
StartDate    datetime64[ns]
EndDate      datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Its still returning empty dataframe note that my start and end date are np.datetime64() and in dataframe StartDate and EndDate are datetime64[ns]

Comment: check the screen shot attached

Comment: Nevermind found the mistake its on my side thanks for the answer its working properly

Comment: What if i want to get multiple records like if i set start date to 2016-01-14 and end date to 2017-09-18 how can i get all the records between them?